# Loop for taking element if other = 1 (from a row)

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to have a loop which will go through all elements, and if LoggedIn='1' then it should take country from this row, and then I will connect to the other table, and increment this row, where country=country from 1st table, but I don't know how to start this loop (I mean I don't know how to do if LoggedIn='1', then take this row's country). This is my code:

```
<?php 
    require_once("config.php");

    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    $take = "SELECT * FROM acc WHERE LoggedIn='1'";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $take);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data))
    {

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just correct your sql

`SELECT * FROM acc WHERE LoggedIn = "1"`

no need to filter the data in php if you can narrow down your results with sql

now I dont know what you with incerent mean so I wait for an edit or comment to help your further

Comment: haha it may seems stupid, but I had only problem how to start, the other part of my script I have done, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

OK, first off this isn't a great question.  A simple Google search should help you to your solution - every tutorial of MySQL will cover `SELECT` and `WHERE` query's, every PHP tutorial will cover iterative loops.

You don't want to query the whole database and then loop over it within PHP when you can limit that dataset by simply using

```
SELECT country FROM table WHERE loggedin = 1
```